# smtp tls configuration

Tags: tls

I've configured a company postfix server for requiring always starttls before any smtp command is used.

The problem is that if configured so, I start receiving lots of errors in the logs like:

```
400 STARTTLS is required first.
```

This is, someone trying to send me an email.

If my server is asked with ehlo, these are the options (among others):

```
250-STARTTLS
```

So, if my server is offering STARTTLS, why the hell the other end choose not to use it? Shouldn't be those servers removed from the earth for being insecure?

Besides, this post [postfix TLS](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html) states that "According to RFC 2487 this MUST NOT be applied in case of a publicly-referenced Postfix SMTP server. This option is off by default and should only seldom be used."

Don't understand why plain smtp commands should be allowed at all, nowadays everything is secured but smtp, one of the most used services. Can someone explain this?

Comment: the person that downvoted this questions don't understand the question and never has configured a mailserver. I'm sure (Have you tried to send and email with telnet?, try it and you'll understand).

Answer (score 3):

From the graphs and responses I see (admittedly mostly 2014 and 2015) it looks like for incoming mail, only about 60% of servers support STARTTLS.  Is that insane?  Yes, of course it is.  It is, however, reality.  The advice to not require STARTTLS is still, unfortunately, valid.

[Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/protect-the-graph/the-current-state-of-smtp-starttls-deployment/1453015901605223/) has some 2014 info, though spot googling doesn't show that number has budged that much since.

Comment: Wow, that's madness.  We need to come up with a STARTTLS everywhere project ourselves.  Maybe google could do something if they would consider non-TLS SMTP inscure on their SMTP servers, just like browsers are scaremongering people about HTTPS.

Comment: It is probably going to take Google or Microsoft swinging that stick, yeah. I think they are mostly currently pushing DMARC in the mail space - they probably figure pushing one standard at a time makes sense. Hopefully once they get good uptake on DMARC, they will go after clear text smtp.